Help with Curve Design for a Miniature Race Track
 Hey everyone! I need some advice on designing the curves for a miniature race track that I’m building for a school project. The track is 39.37 inches long and 15.5 inches wide, with a lane width of about 6 inches. The car I’m using is 8 inches long, 4 inches wide, and powered by a hydraulic system using a syringe mechanism, which means it doesn’t steer manually. Instead, the curves need to guide the car naturally, allowing it to navigate smoothly without hitting the edges.
What would be the ideal curve radius for the turns to ensure that the car moves smoothly? Are there specific measurements, equations, or techniques you’d recommend to create accurate curves with cardboard?
For reference, the design is inspired by the layout of Daytona International Speedway, aiming for smooth oval curves that allow continuous motion. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

How are your cars steered? Put the info in your question - not here in the comments - so that all the information is in the one place. A sketch would help. Does a car run in one lane and race a car in another? Are the tracks offset a fixed distance from the outer wall? Welcome to E.SE.

Your dimensions don't make a whole lot of sense. Two 6 inch lanes in a layout that's only 15.5 inches wide doesn't leave much room for anything else, let alone smooth curves.

You're not going to be able to steer the car based on banking the curves. You would have some chance if the circuit had a constant curvature but it doesn't - it has both curves and straighs (or straghtish).

If consider the setup for the straight, we find that the steering must be stright and all wheels will travel the same distance.
If we consider motion in the curves we realise that the distance covered by the wheels on the inside of the trace is less than the distance covered by the outside wheels. The steering has to compensate for this.

Mechanical solutions include cutting a slot in the track (Electric slot-car racing does this) and add a guide pin or steering mechanism to the car.

Figure 1. Slot car steering mechanism. Image source: SlotForum.com.
Electro mechanical solutions include fitting a model servo actuator to the car to do the steering based on feedback from a buried wire. I think this would be complex and take you away from your primary focus.
Another idea would be to bias the car slightly towards one of the wall and have a probe or small wheel to turn the steering a little if the wall is contacted.
Have fun!

Even more complex, you can use "bicycle steering" so that the car automatically turns into banked turns when running at the correct speed. (There is an almost magical feeling riding a m/c at the speed which matches the road)
